# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\cat-and-dog\training_set\training_set'

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to python. I tried to run the CNN classification code. Kindly help me to solve this error.

Comment: Why is it `'D:\\..\..'`?

Comment: I suppose you are missing the file extension, can you please share the code you are trying to run?

Comment: the error line is this: training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:\cat-and-dog\training_set\training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')

Comment: taken form the blog below: https://becominghuman.ai/building-an-image-classifier-using-deep-learning-in-python-totally-from-a-beginners-perspective-be8dbaf22dd8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use forward slashes instead of backslashes.
This works:

```
os.chdir("d:/cat-and-dog/training_set/training_set")
```

But this doesn't:

```
 os.chdir("d:\cat-and-dog\training_set\training_set")
```

You can also use double forward slashes:

```
os.chdir("d://cat-and-dog/training_set/training_set")
```

You can also use double forward slashes the whole time:

```
os.chdir("d://cat-and-dog//training_set//training_set")
```

Comment: While it's *recommended*, it doesn't **need** - backslashes work as well on a filesystem where they are native. Backslashes just have to be used correctly, such that they are not considered escapes (eg. in string literals). (Random note: the Windows File API internally accepts forward slashes, even without any transformations in applications themselves.)